# Does vi.stackexchange want "tech support" questions from ALE?

Tags: discussion

**Updates**:

- The link has been corrected to "Stack Exchange" with the proper syntax (4 Dec.)
- The issue on GitHub was closed by w0rp, stating that no discussion was had (4 Dec.)
- Related: [How much should we indulge questions about plugins?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21/how-much-should-we-indulge-questions-about-plugins?rq=1)

---

## TL;DR

I have some concerns about a recent commit I saw on ALE's repo, encouraging users to ask their "tech support" questions about ALE here.

I'm not 100% up-to-date on our consensus about plugin questions, though I cite the help page below.

- Is this something vi.stackexchange wants?
- Does it fit our model/draw the kinds of questions we are looking for/stay on-topic?
- Has this been done successfully with other plugins?
- Has this been discussed?

  - If so, where can I find the results?
  - If not, should we? (Hence this post...)

---

Follow-up on Meta for an issue posted [on ALE's Github](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/issues/2115) (reproduced here for posterity):

In reference to: [146769c61671ebfb25cc7efd7acdc35a6a1d33da](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/commit/146769c61671ebfb25cc7efd7acdc35a6a1d33da)

Has the ALE community discussed with the vi.stackexchange community (of which I am also a member) this type of recommendation? Are there meta posts that can be linked to describe the decision surrounding this recommendation, what's on & off topic specifically with regards to ALE, etc.? (A [quick search](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=ale) reveals, alas, the answer is *no*.)

The commit came as a surprise to me, though I monitor vi.stackexchange pretty closely. It seems like we should be more intentional with how we interact with that community, especially since we already get a number of questions there that are more easily answerable by plugin maintainers and communities (and we often redirect them to the Issues tracker of Github repos).

Also see this [help center article](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) about on-topic-ness, from where I draw the following quote:

> Questions about Vim plugins are on topic but be aware that bug reports and feature requests for a plugin would be better off in that plugin's issue tracker. Most of the plugins available on Github use the built-in issue tracker. (The "Issues" tab in the top menu.)

---

Part of the diff:

```
Are you having trouble configuring ALE? You should ask tech support style
questions for ALE on [https://vi.stackexchange.com/](Stack Overflow) or perhaps
on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/) instead. GitHub issues are for
reporting problems with software, not for tech support.
```

In fact, I would argue that vi.stackexchange (and just about every other vim plugin on github that I know of) encourages and expects GitHub issues to be used for engaging with the dev community to ask questions about the software: if ALE maintainers would feel better with an FAQ/Wiki, a dedicated Q&A site, or some other mechanism, I recommend they take the time to create one, rather than shunt their problem onto others.

I at vi.stackexchange am *also* not for tech support.

Comment: Someone with more Meta presence and better understanding of the tags in use, please feel free to fix my tags.

Comment: In the past I've noticed that *a lot* of ALE issues are just basic Vim-usage kind of questions, and not bug reports or feature requests. Those kind of "how do I do X?" or "I tried it and it doesn't work" kind of questions seem basically on-topic to me (the last one *may* be a bug, but more often than not it's not).

Comment: A bit related meta FAQ on Stack Overflow: [Why we're not customer support for 'your favorite company'](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/2821954). Might be better to clarify with them what kind of questions are on-topic on [vi.se] and some guidance. And also fix the markdown link ([vi.se] is not [so]...)

Comment: As w0rp said in the comment to the github issue, they decided this by themselves without contacting our community (which might not be the best way to do it). I think that with this kind of suggestions we will need to pay a lot of attention to the duplicate questions, otherwise the risk is to see this site flooded by the same basic questions about installation which don't create a lot of value.

Comment: I'm asking the wider community to talk to each other and help each other, rather than putting the responsibility entirely on me and a small number of regular contributors. I'm frustrated because I can't handle the volume of emails. The people posting questions will be frustrated because they aren't getting answers.

Answer (score 2):

Personally — speaking as a member of the community, and not a moderator — I don't really see a problem with this.

This site is an appropriate platform for asking technical questions, including questions on how to use a plugin. We [already have a few questions about ALE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plugin-ale), and at a glance most of them seem okay.

This is a fairly small site with a low influx of questions every day; we can always re-evaluate *if* it becomes a problem (I don't expect it will).

A lot of the problems that happened on Stack Overflow are because companies/projects that were redirecting to Stack Overflow were either completely off-topic (e.g. hosting providers), or communicated it in such a way that implied that *all* support questions could be asked there, including non-programming ones. I don't really see these problems here.

Some people have since taken this as a "never redirect to Stack Overflow", but in general it's not an issue. Sure, people following a "ask tech questions here" links can ask bad questions, but so do other people. I'm not sure if there is a strong correlation.

---

I'd also like to add some background to the above: in my experience maintaining a popular Vim plugin can be a frustrating experience, even more so than maintaining open source projects in general.

A *lot* of issues on the bug tracker are very unclear and posted by people who, frankly put, have no idea what they're doing. They don't know Vim; they don't know the language they're working with; they don't know Unix/Linux basics. You really have to take them by the hand and guide them.

Don't get me wrong, it's not that I mind helping people out who are new to Vim and confused — I think my contributions here are proof enough of that — but there's a time and place for everything, and while I don't mind *in general* to guide new people along, I don't want to spend my entire waking life doing so. Sometimes I just want to talk to people who know what they're doing. When I contribute to open source I am, for the most part, [just DIY-ing](https://arp242.net/weblog/diy.html). Back when I was more active in maintaining vim-go half the time I was helping people make sense of basics such as GOPATH, and it wasn't fun.

You typically don't get a whole lot of long-term help with maintaining software projects. Sure, there are people who drop by and contribute a few patches, but people who consistently do the "gruntwork" over a long period of time are rare. In the specific example of ALE it's mostly just w0rp  (I planned to do a lot more work on ALE, but stuff happened that made me end up in New Zealand, and now I don't have a lot of time, I still hope to work on it *Soon*™).

So if "offloading" some of the maintenance burden to this site makes life easier for w0rp, then I don't see why not? I know some people have a rather purist view of what Stack Exchange should and shouldn't be, but I am not one of them. There are limits, but as mentioned, general questions about Vim usage (including plugins) have always been on-topic since this site was started, and as long as the questions are useful, answerable, and not wildly off-topic I don't see what the problem is with a plugin linking to us.