# Is vi/Vim the place to ask plugin configuration question

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering how much the question about plugin and plugin configuration are part of the scope of the vi/Vim SE site?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How much should we indulge questions about plugins?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21/51) – not entirely sure if I follow what you mean with "part of the score of the site" though?

Comment: Thanks I vote to close the question. I could also delete it. I asked because some answers let me feel that question about plugin should be redirected to issue tracker of the plugin. But it seems that I missunderstood. The voted answer consider that plugin question are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you meant “scope” instead of “score”?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Some type of plugin questions are better asked at the issue tracker, mostly those involving actual bugs, because the plugin authors are in a better position to help people, but those questions aren't necessarily off-topic here either. In general I *hate* people posting generic "use the issue tracker" type of comments because it's just "buzz off, go away" ("you may have better luck at the issue tracker" is a different type of comment and okay).

Comment: Thanks @MartinTournoij, we have the same understanding. Of course if we identify it is a bug in a plugin or in Vim/Neovim it is better to redirect to the issue tracker. But otherwise we want to welcome the user with their plugin configuration problems.