# What is the target audience and the type of questions accepted on the site?

Tags: discussion

Vim documentation is very good. There are a lot of internet resources available on the Internet about Vim. There are very few questions that can't be answered about Vim using these resources.

Looking at past questions, answers and votes, I identify a variety of profiles using the sites:

1. Vim experts answering the questions
2. Advanced Vim users (e.g. plugins writers) struggling with difficult problems
3. Vim users in search of gaining experience
4. Vim newbies asking questions

Are all these public equally welcome?

Do we want to narrow our focus?

Comment: Related: [1](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1573/10604), [2](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21/10604).

Answer (score 2):

My view is that our community is very small (~1300 people) and that we should keep all the profiles.

We have people that knows the code and the history of Vim and are able to answer precisely to very complex questions.

We have very experienced users that knows very well Vim's philosophy and are able to guide users through all the ways to use Vim to highlight the most promising.

We have Vim enthusiasts that like to learn, share their knowledge and help others.

We have Vim users that like to be read about Vim problems and learn from the answers. If you analyze how people votes you noticed that there is a share amount of people that appreciate to learn basic functionalities (easily available from the documentation) from reading questions.

We have newbies that are intimidated by Vim and like to ask questions to solve their problems but probably also to feel that they are supported by a community that is willing to guide them through something that still look as a maze to them. If you analyze new questions you see that there a bunch of users asking repeatedly questions, some relatively easy to answer but that gather votes from others.

I understand that very experienced user get tired from answering again and again the same questions.

I can imagine that a vision of the site focusing on only the two first categories and that would probably make the site more focus and better for them.

Giving the size of the community I believe it is better to keep all the profiles. I believe all the learners (3 and 4) benefits of the questions and answers. I believe it is possible to organize that the experts can select the questions they answer.

Of course this is only my view and I'm interested that other point of are expressed.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that there should be a place for everybody in our community. Our community is small but it's also heterogeneous and diverse. Our common ground is that we all use Vim (or at least some flavor of Vi).

We should be liberal in the questions we allow. There's no such thing as a stupid question. Vim novices will find things hard that more seasoned Vimmers do every day. I believe questions about plugins are on-topic: there's no Vim plugin without Vim. Also, there's no other place for people to ask questions about Vim plugins. Who will answer them if we don't do it?
And let's not forget that even the best of documentations will have its gaps, shortcomings and mistakes -  yes, even `:help`! When in doubt, accept the question.
Also, "RTFM" (in one of its many forms) is never an acceptable comment or answer.

Initially, I wrote about our diversity and I believe this diversity is also our strong side. Under no circumstances should we try to suppress it. Even if it may be inconvenient at times.

---

Maybe I'm reading too much into this question and your answer, Vivian, but I can't shake off the impression this is indirectly about romainl's comments in [Get default autocomplete list using Vimscript](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/44112/get-default-autocomplete-list-using-vimscript)
There, it's out in the open now.

First, I won't comment on what romainl wrote. I'm lucky not to be in a profession that judges people.

I see this question both as my personal failure because I couldn't be helpful (I was decidedly unhelpful) and a failure of our community as a whole. Let's face it, we botched it.

If you have a disagreement with somebody, the right way is to confront them and talk it over. Ask someone to moderate if you're concerned the discussion may escalate.
A question on meta like this one will most likely go unregistered.

Having said that, I'm also convinced of the ultimate futility of this enterprise. People don't change because of half an hour's chat.

As I said, accept and embrace everybody - including the occasionally grumpy ones.

---

In finishing, I think the underlying problem is that the SE format is not fair to new users at all. I've seen so many instances (mostly on SO) where new users felt bullied to delete their questions.

These people sign up and post what we would call a bad question. They are immediately faced with three downvotes, comments like "Don't post pictures of code", "Take the tour, read how to ask?" or "Nobody can help you unless you share your real code" - you all know it. Then somebody edits their question to "fix typos and grammar". All of these reactions are warranted - but is it any wonder people give up at this point?

I know I've done my own share of harassing new users - without knowing it or wanting to do so.

I don't have a solution for it. Let's try to be better.

To end on a positive note: Vi and Vim SE is **by far the most friendly SE** I'm actively contributing to. We have a welcoming community and great moderators. We should strive to improve but things aren't all that bad.

Comment: Thanks for you answer @Friedrich. My question is a true question. There are forum like reedit and others and it would be a valuable answer to says that the SE should only gather precise questions and precise answer. Indeed the behavior of some of our very valuable members make me doubt that my community view of Vi/Vim was shared. I wrote the question and the answer to try to asses how much it was shared and how much I should bend it. But different vision could of course coexist and like in every group we have to take people as they are and seek alignment only at the margin :-)

Comment: Thanks again for your contribution to the debate.

Comment: As a member of a community, you can always try to shape and change the community (for the better, of course). You can only do so much and hope others catch on. Some will never and that's okay, too. For me, **this site is by far the friendliest SE** where I'm actively contributing. SO is somewhere in the middle range.